# How do I determine the server's MAXDOP setting in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

I see lots of sites that show how to set it, but I just want to see what it is first.  What is the command to do this?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

**In Script:**

```
EXEC sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1
GO
RECONFIGURE
GO
EXEC sp_configure 'max degree of parallelism'
GO
```

Comment: This does not work on Azure SQL Database.

Answer (score 42):

More simply if you wish to use a pure SQL script you can use the following which will give you the values for both 'cost threshold for parallelism' and 'max degree of parallelism' or many other things if you remove the WHERE clause ;)

Edited the following to limit to one row

```
SELECT
    name,
    value_in_use
FROM
    sys.configurations
WHERE
    description LIKE '%max%%parallelism%'
```

Comment: This one is good if you don't have permissions to reconfigure

Answer (score 0):

For Azure SQL:

```
SELECT [value] FROM sys.database_scoped_configurations WHERE [name] = 'MAXDOP';
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/configure-max-degree-of-parallelism